# copy command in DOS is not recognizing when filename has '='

Tags: batch-file, command, dos, filenames

I wrote batch script to copy a file and write a log.
However `copy` is not working when the file name is like this:

```
8001#121122213500#1002#00#M=MRN100#C=Test_Large_File2.wav
```

On further checking I found this is because of the  `=` in the filename.

I also tested individually. When I use `copy *.wav d:\wav` file is getting copied, but when I use

```
copy 8001#121122213500#1002#00#M=MRN100#C=Test_Large_File2.wav d:\wav
```

I get an message that the file is not found.

Can any one help me in resolving this. I also tried searching old posts here but couldn't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the filename

```
copy "8001#121122213500#1002#00#M=MRN100#C=Test_Large_File2.wav" d:\wav
```

Comment: Your welcome. If this answered your question just check the tick to show it as accepted.

Comment: +1: The same is true for any file name that contains a token delimiter, including space, `,` and `;`